# How many hours do I need to complete Fallout-3?

Tags: fallout-3

I've bought Fallout-3 second hand last year and for time reason, I've just played part of the tutorial at the beginning.

How many hours do I need to enjoy and finish Fallout-3?

Comment: I've put 80 hours into the game.thats including storyline,side missions,finding all the bobbleheads etc...I also bought purchased 1 expansion pack and have put an additional 15 hours in the game.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It really does depend on you. I know people who have clocked 400+ hours on the game and loved every minute of it. I also know from first hand experience that it can be completed (main storyline, no DLC) in a day if you know exactly where you are going and what you are doing.

Comment: what do you mean with DLC?

Comment: @system: DLC = "Downloadable Content." Bethesda issued several [expansions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/2352/58) for it. If you have/buy them, they will add significantly to your hours-to-complete. Which is why most of us bought them. :) (As said by someone with over 400 hours across at least 3 play-throughs in Fallout 3 ... )

Comment: One day? That's hardcore. It took me a long time to get through that game, though I did do a number of the side missions instead of a straight run-through. Still, I'd think a minimum of 15 hours or so. Well, I guess that technically could be done in a day...

Comment: Don't worry about time, you'll not have the best experience.  Fallout 3 for me was exteremly enjoyable, there are so many things you can do, and the world is huge and detailed.  I loved uncovering everythign about what happened (I never played F1 or F2).  Take your time, explore, go into every nook and cranny, you won't regret it.

Answer (score 2):

It does depend on what you want to do. If you stay focussed on following the main storylines, you can easily complete the game very quickly. If you want to include major side-quests, as well as all achievements, I'd say around **50 hours**.

You can probably bring that time down considerably if you use a guide to only go to locations where there's a quest. The trick is to stay focussed and not get tempted to wander (although I'm sure many would argue that the exploration is the best aspect of the game).

I almost got fed up with the amount of time this game was taking to complete, but I'm glad I finally finished it (although the ending stinks -- Get **Broken Steel** to have a better ending).

Comment: have you enjoyed it?

Comment: I did at first, then I got tired of the fact that there seemed to be no end in sight. I stopped playing it for ages. Eventually I went back and was more focussed on getting through things quickly; Getting achievements, finishing missions, etc. I used the Fallout 3 Wikia to make a note of where the locations that would help where, too. I did less exploration, but yes, I did enjoy it.

Comment: For me I loved the detail of the world, and really enjoyed exploring.  I didn't have to try and ended up with new quests added, but it was the exploring that was most fun for me, the quests gave me reasons to explore certain areas.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how fast you are doing the main storyline.. If you dont have any of the DLC's, it can take less than a day. If you have DLC's, then it only means more playtime  and more fun.

If you are going to start at fallout 3 now, enjoy! :)